# extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot I need use  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for use "CORS".

But When I put "extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" I have error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   ServiciosConfig.java    /tutorial/src/main/java/com/service/configure   line 1  Java Problem
```

I updated pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With version :

```
<version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
```

Code:

```
package com.service.configure;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.service.services")
@PropertySource("file:${ruta_properties}")
public class ServiciosConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${usrRest}")
    private String usrRest; 

    @Value("${passRest}")
    private String passRest; 


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    // To allow Pre-flight [OPTIONS] request from browser
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(usrRest).password(passRest).roles("USER");

    }

}
```

The error begins in `package com.service.configure;`  in `p` When I remove extends , `package` doesn't errors... But I can't use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` obvius...

Edit pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>tutorial</name>
    <description>Project tutorial</description>

        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

       <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
      <!-- JPA Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

           <!-- MySQL Connector-J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Tomcat embedded container -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

          <!-- Data REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Comment: i tried your code it work for me

Comment: please post pom.xml file

Comment: @Ganesh Patil , I updated with pom.xml

Comment: I also tried with your pom.xml and it works for me

Comment: If I do click in package (lamp) the help is "Configure build Path"

Comment: try to maven-update project

Comment: I create other class I see that I can extends , but the methos "  configure(HttpSecurity http) and configure(WebSecurity web) I have error.

Answer (score 14):

change your dependency to use this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will solve teh problem

Comment: It worked for me when I added a version like this:

`<version>5.7.3</version>`

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was deprecated.

Refer the below link:

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
..
In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration

Read below article by spring itself which shows multiple things changed in new spring versions.
https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I deleted my repo in .m2 folder and rebuild the application in cmd using command :
mvn clean install -U
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

then

```
package com.amazone.admin.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import 
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig  {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
{
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz)->authz.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting similar errors. This is because spring security config deprecated the class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter from version 5.4.
I had added below dependency to resolve the error-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this parent version, the issue resolved for me

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the solution

Add pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

But When I run the program I get other error...

[PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167664/passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null)